# When specifically does a function scope (frame) get deleted?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been learning some Python in my spare time through online exercises (this is from Berkeley's CS61A). I'm now trying to get an intuitive sense of frames but evidently, I still haven't got one.

```
def print_sums(n):
    print(n)
    def next_sum(k):
        return print_sums(n + k)
    return next_sum

print_sums(1)(3)(5)
```

I take it that when the code above runs, it first binds the name print_sums to the function object print_sums(n) [parent = Global].

When **print_sums(1)**(3)(5) is run, the function call in **bold** is evaluated first.

A frame f1: print_sums [parent = Global] is now created. Which is now our current frame. The name next_sum is now bound to the function object next_sum(k) [parent = f1].

**Then print_sums(1) returns next_sum.**

I take it that when the above happens, the code would 'look' (to the computer at least), like this:

```
def print_sums(n):
    print(n)
    def next_sum(k):
        return print_sums(n + k)
    return next_sum

next_sum(3)(5)
```

Now since the function call print_sums(1) has returned a value, I also take it that the current frame is now back to Global.

Now the computer attempts to run next_sum(3), **but since next_sum is a name which was defined in f1, and wasn't in Global, shouldn't Python throw out an error along the lines of 'the next_sum is not assigned?'**

I guess what I'm trying to learn is when exactly does Python exit a frame, isn't it when a return statement has been evoked?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)

Comment: In python, functions behave like any other python object. When you write `def next_sum(k): [...]`, you create a python object, which also happens to be callable, which can then be returned like any other object from a function. Maybe the following comparison helps: If you had a function `def foo():` with a local variable `x = 5` and `return x`, would you expect an error like `x is not assigned` after calling the function and using its return value?

Comment: What does "print_sums(n) [parent = Global]" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The frame itself is generally deleted when it is exited, which happens when you think it does, the return statement being a common case. The values that were defined in that frame can live outside of it.

The code doesn't 'look' like the below, as you suggested:

```
def print_sums(n):
    print(n)
    def next_sum(k):
        return print_sums(n + k)
    return next_sum

next_sum(3)(5)
```

because as you say, `next_sum` isn't defined in the global scope. `print_sums(1)` returns a function object which is not bound to any variable name.

Similarly, if you had a function:

```
def foo():
    x = 1 + 2
    return x
```

then `print(foo())` wouldn't complain that `x` is not defined. Really the variable name is irrelevant to other scopes. You could change it to a new name or remove it entirely and the effect would be the same:

```
def foo():
    return 1 + 2
```

On a different but related note, the function object `next_sum` (or `print_sums(1)`) holds a reference to the value of `n` in its closure:

```
print(print_sums(13).__closure__[0].cell_contents)  # 13
```

Comment: okay so let me get this right: the return statement behaves in such a way that the name next_sum is evaluated first before being output as a function object func next_sum(k) [parent = f1], and this function object has all the 'information' necessary to take in the value 3 as k and spit out print_sums(n + k)? 

i.e. The function object has the complete definition of the function within it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you:

```
def print_sums(n):
"""
stateless function.
n is a local var and is destroyed after the return of the function.
(but the value of n has influence on the definition of the function "next_sum".)
"""
print(n)
def next_sum(k):
    return print_sums(n + k)
return next_sum

print_sums(1)(3)(5)

# run it once
print_sum_with_offset_1 = print_sums(1) # print 1, the local n in the function is 1
# back in the global scope -> the value n=1 exists only(!) in the definition of print_sum_with_offset_1.
print_sum_with_offset_4 = print_sum_with_offset_1(3)
print_sum_with_offset_4(5)

# this was just to show, that print_sums(..) is stateless
print_sum_with_offset_3 = print_sums(3) # print 3, because given n is 3
```

Comment: I don't think your code is identical to mine. Mine prints out 1, 3, and 9 and not 1, 3, 4

Comment: Updated it. Now it does the same